# How to make child Tkinter object trigger a change in parent's widget

Tags: python, tkinter

*Edit: thanks to @jasonharper's comments below I can ask a more informed question:*

I have a main app, and a separate module `snipping_tool.py` that handles creating a new window with the option to screen-snip or select an image file. I want `snipping_tool.py` to provide an image to the main app, but currently I'm trying to retrieve the image too soon (before the `snipping_tool` window even opens).

How can I wait until the user selects or grabs an image before I try to assign `MyNewObject.selected_image`? Should I use a `binding` or some event handler? (I have limited experience with both). Or is there a simpler way?

**Simplified Main App:**

```
import tkinter as tk
import snipping_tool

class MinCodeEx:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.ButtonA = tk.Button(width=60,height=40,command = lambda: self.UpdateImg(master))
        self.ButtonA.pack()
    def UpdateImg(self, master):
        newDialog = snipping_tool.AcquireImage(self.master)
        # self.ButtonA['image'] = newDialog.image_selected
        #if newDialog.image_selected:
        self.ButtonA.config(image=newDialog.image_selected)
        print(newDialog.image_selected)

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    MinCodeEx(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**snipping_tool.py**

returns *None* instead of an image file since I'm trying to retrieve the `selected_image` too soon.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageGrab, ImageTk, Image
import cv2
import numpy as np
from tkinter import filedialog


class ScreenSnip(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.image = None

    def get_snip(self):
        self.configure(cursor='cross')
        self.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
        self.attributes('-alpha', 0.4)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg='dark gray')
        self.canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        self.begin_x = 0
        self.begin_y = 0
        self.end_x = 0
        self.end_y = 0
        self.click_drag = False

        self.canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0, outline='#0052d6', width=2, fill='white', tags='snip_rect')
        self.canvas.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', self.mousePressEvent)
        self.canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.mouseMoveEvent)
        self.canvas.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.mouseReleaseEvent)

        print('Capture the screen...')

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.begin_x = event.x
        self.begin_y = event.y
        print(self.begin_x,self.begin_y)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.click_drag = True
        self.end_x = event.x
        self.cur_y = event.y
        width = self.end_x - self.begin_x
        height = abs(width * 2/3)
        if self.cur_y < self.begin_y:
            height *= -1
        self.end_y = self.begin_y + height
        self.canvas.coords('snip_rect', self.begin_x, self.begin_y, self.end_x, self.end_y)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.destroy()
        self.master.update_idletasks()
        self.master.after(100)  # give time for screen to be refreshed so as not to see the blue box on the screenshot
        if not self.click_drag: # if the user just clicks, instead of clicking and dragging
            self.begin_x -= 300
            self.begin_y += 200
            self.end_x = self.begin_x + 600
            self.end_y = self.begin_y - 400
        x1 = min(self.begin_x, self.end_x)
        y1 = min(self.begin_y, self.end_y)
        x2 = max(self.begin_x, self.end_x)
        y2 = max(self.begin_y, self.end_y)

        self.img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x1, y1, x2, y2))
        self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)
        #self.img = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(img), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        #cv2.imshow('Captured Image', self.img)
        #cv2.waitKey(0)

font1 = ("arial", 18, "bold")

class AcquireImage:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.nWin = tk.Toplevel(master)
        self.fontA = ("arial", 20, "bold")

        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.nWin, bg="#1B2631")
        self.frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        self.button1 = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Select Image File", padx=10, pady=10, bg="#d9a193",
                              font = self.fontA, command =lambda: self.show_dialogs(1))
        self.button1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")#, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.button2 = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Get Screen Snip", padx=10, pady=10, bg="#d9a193",
                              font = self.fontA, command=lambda: self.show_dialogs(2))
        self.button2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")#, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.image_selected = None

    def show_dialogs(self, method): ###################  THIS IS WHERE THE IMAGE IS SELECTED ###########

        if method == 1:
            ret = filedialog.askopenfilename()
            if ret:
                self.image_selected = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = ret)
                self.nWin.destroy()

        elif method == 2:
            newWin = ScreenSnip(self.nWin)
            newWin.get_snip()
            ret = newWin.image
            if ret:
                self.image_selected = ret


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    AcquireImage(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Merely creating an instance of `AcquireImage` doesn't actually acquire anything: it just creates a window with buttons to allow the user to do so.  But you're checking its `image_selected` attribute immediately after creating the instance - at that point in time, the buttons *aren't even visible yet* (returning to the mainloop will be required for the GUI to update), much less been clicked by the user.  One possible approach would be to pass a callback function to `AcquireImage()`, that will be called (with the image as a parameter) once there's actually an image acquired.

Comment: @jasonharper, that makes total sense. Thanks for explaining. I assumed it would continue to loop past that `if` statement. Could you give a simple callback example? I understand what you're saying conceptually.

Comment: Or maybe a better question is, where should I put the callback function? Inside of `AquireImage`? And then call it from within `UpdateImg`? I'm not certain of what the `mainloop` loops over.

Comment: How do I know when the user finished selecting an image? (to trigger a callback)

Comment: Basically, whenever you're currently assigning to `self.image_selected`, you'd instead call the callback (that the main program provided) with that image as a parameter.  That should work for acquiring an image from a file, but I see that you have the same basic problem in `ScreenSnip` - you instantiate the class, and are immediately expecting to have an image, even though none of the user interactions required to define the snipping area have occurred yet.  So you'll need to pass on the callback to that class, to call when it finally performs the actual snip.

Comment: @jasonharper I'm assigning `self.image_selected` from inside of the child `AquireImage` so how could I use this to trigger a callback in the parent main program? Would I need to use a `binding`? In other words: the child `AquireImage` doesn't know about the existence of `ButtonA`. So how could a function within the child trigger a function within the parent (or modify a widget within the parent)?

Comment: The main program would need to pass the callback to `AcquireImage`, which would store it in `self.callback` perhaps.  It would then call `self.callback(image)` at the point where it actually has an image.  The callback function that the main program passes would know about `ButtonA`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219699/discussion-between-wes-tomer-and-jasonharper).

Answer (score 0):

@jasonharper was right. This solution is derived from his comments.

When I create an instance of `AcquireImage` I also pass `ButtonA` as a parameter so that I can modify its image. Within `AcquireImage` I first get a new image (either by snipping it, or with the file explorer) and then to avoid garbage collection immediately deleting it, I save it by assigning it to `ButtonA.img`. (I first create the `.img` part of ButtonA in the main program). Once I have the image, I can then assign it.

> I probably could have also solved this issue by creating a function
> within the main program that changes the image of whatever widget is
> passed to it as a parameter. I could then pass this function to the
> instance of `AcquireImage` with `ButtonA` as a parameter. It might
> have looked something like this in the main program: `def callback(i_file):    ButtonA['image'] = i_file newDialog = snipping_tool.AcquireImage(self.master, self.callback)` Later I
> would have `AcquireImage` initialized/defined with
> `self.some_function` as the second argument (after master), and I
> could pass the image file to it. At least that's how I probably could
> have done it.

This is how I actually solved it:

**MAIN APP**

```
import tkinter as tk
import snipping_tool
waitingforImage = True
class MinCodeEx:
    global waitingforImage
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.ButtonA = tk.Button(width=60,height=40,command = lambda: self.UpdateImg())
        self.ButtonA.pack()
        self.ButtonA.img = None

    def UpdateImg(self):
        newDialog = snipping_tool.AcquireImage(self.master, self.ButtonA)

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    MinCodeEx(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**snipping_tool.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageGrab, ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import filedialog


class ScreenSnip(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master, changeThis):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.image = None
        self.master = master
        self.changeThis = changeThis

    def get_snip(self):
        self.configure(cursor='cross')
        self.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
        self.attributes('-alpha', 0.4)
        print("attempting to create tk.Canvas for get_snip")
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg='dark gray')
        self.canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        self.begin_x = 0
        self.begin_y = 0
        self.end_x = 0
        self.end_y = 0
        self.click_drag = False

        self.canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0, outline='#0052d6', width=2, fill='white', tags='snip_rect')
        self.canvas.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', self.mousePressEvent)
        self.canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.mouseMoveEvent)
        self.canvas.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.mouseReleaseEvent)

        print('Capture the screen...')

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.begin_x = event.x
        self.begin_y = event.y
        print(self.begin_x,self.begin_y)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.click_drag = True
        self.end_x = event.x
        self.cur_y = event.y
        width = self.end_x - self.begin_x
        height = abs(width * 2/3)
        if self.cur_y < self.begin_y:
            height *= -1
        self.end_y = self.begin_y + height
        self.canvas.coords('snip_rect', self.begin_x, self.begin_y, self.end_x, self.end_y)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.destroy()
        self.master.update_idletasks()
        self.master.after(100)  # give time for screen to be refreshed so as not to see the blue box on the screenshot
        if not self.click_drag: # if the user just clicks, instead of clicking and dragging
            self.begin_x -= 300
            self.begin_y += 200
            self.end_x = self.begin_x + 600
            self.end_y = self.begin_y - 400
        x1 = min(self.begin_x, self.end_x)
        y1 = min(self.begin_y, self.end_y)
        x2 = max(self.begin_x, self.end_x)
        y2 = max(self.begin_y, self.end_y)

        self.img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x1, y1, x2, y2))
        print("getting image grab")
        self.changeThis.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)
        self.changeThis['image'] = self.changeThis.img

font1 = ("arial", 18, "bold")

class AcquireImage:
    def __init__(self, master, changeThis):
        self.master = master
        self.changeThis = changeThis
        self.nWin = tk.Toplevel(master)
        self.fontA = ("arial", 20, "bold")

        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.nWin, bg="#1B2631")
        self.frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        self.button1 = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Select Image File", padx=10, pady=10, bg="#d9a193",
                              font = self.fontA, command =lambda: self.show_dialogs(1))
        self.button1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")#, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.button2 = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Get Screen Snip", padx=10, pady=10, bg="#d9a193",
                              font = self.fontA, command=lambda: self.show_dialogs(2))
        self.button2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")#, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.image_selected = None

    def show_dialogs(self, method):
        if method == 1:
            ret = filedialog.askopenfilename() #filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='/home/user/images/')
            self.changeThis.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = ret)
            self.changeThis['image'] = self.changeThis.img
        elif method == 2:
            print("attempting ScreenSnip")
            newWin = ScreenSnip(self.master, self.changeThis)
            newWin.get_snip()
        self.nWin.destroy()

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    bt = tk.Button(root, width = 20, height = 20)
    bt.pack()
    ScreenSnip(root, bt)
    #AcquireImage(root,bt)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I still need to fix one unrelated thing -- the button doesn't fit the size of the image that I select or grab. It always ends up being a small square.